# How to effectively check if numpy array can be cast to another integer type?

Tags: python, numpy, casting

Let's say I have a numpy array of some integer type (say `np.int64`) and want to cast it to another type (say `np.int8`). How can I most effectively check if the operation is safe (preserving all values)?

There are two approaches I've come up with:

Approach 1: Use the type information

```
def is_safe(data, new_type):
    if np.can_cast(data, new_type):
        return True    # Handle the trivial allowed cases
    type_info = np.iinfo(new_type)
    return np.all((data >= type_info.min) & (data <= type_info.max))
```

Approach 2: Use np.can_cast on all items

```
def is_safe(data, new_type):
    if np.can_cast(data, new_type):
        return True    # Handle the trivial allowed cases
    return all(np.can_cast(item, new_type) for item in np.nditer(item))
```

Both of these approaches seem to be valid (and work for trivial cases) but are they correct and efficient? Is there another, better approach?

P.S. To complicate things further, `np.can_cast(np.int8, np.uint64)` returns False (naturally) so changing between signed and unsigned integers has to be checked somewhat separately.

Comment: I don't think the P.S. adds anything new or requires a special check; the fact that `np.uint64` requires values >= 0 is not fundamentally different from `np.int8` requiring values >= -128.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know that the array is of a NumPy integer type, then the only check needed is that the values are within the range specified by min/max of the target integer range. This is a much simpler check than the generic `can_cast`, which has no a priori knowledge of the things it is fed. Consequently, `can_cast` takes longer. I tested this on casting integers 0-99 from np.int64 to np.int8.

So, while both approaches are correct, the first one is preferable if you know  that `data` is a NumPy integer array.

```
>>> timeit.timeit("np.all((data >= type_info.min) & (data <= type_info.max))", setup="import numpy as np\ndata = np.array(range(100), dtype=np.int64)\ntype_info = np.iinfo(np.int8)")
6.745509549000417
>>> timeit.timeit("all(np.can_cast(item, np.uint8) for item in np.nditer(data))", setup="import numpy as np\ndata = np.array(range(100), dtype=np.int64)")
51.0065170609887
```

It is slightly faster (20% or so) to assign the min and max values to new variables:

```
type_info = np.iinfo(new_type)
a = type_info.min
b = type_info.max
return np.all((data >= a) & (data <= b))
```